# How do I merge two Facebook accounts?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I have the problem of having two Facebook accounts by some accident that I wasn't aware of when it happened. Now, since I'm a musician, I don't want to lose the friends from the "smaller" Facebook account. What can I do in this situation? I only have one password!

Answer (score 2):

The [official answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/203498356357867) is no, but MakeUseOf has published a [guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-wont-let-you-merge-accounts-here-is-how-to-do-it-anyways-weekly-facebook-tips/) that outlines the most expedient way of combining two accounts, which relies upon downloading an archive of your Facebook data and re-importing some of the information into your new, "merged" account.

Data such as friends and photos are more easily re-imported than your timeline and news feed history, which there is unfortunately no way of transplanting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply invite all your friends to bigger Facebook profile with a sweet message & close the smaller account.

At this time, two account merger isn't possible.